# Picturebox.Image.Dispose is causing ArgumentException?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to create a remote-desktop application, with a client and server (of-course).

But i found a weird problem, in this code: (in which the bytes() contains the desktop screenshot sent by the client.

```
 Public Sub HandleDesktopInfo(ByVal client As ServerClient, ByVal bytes As Byte())
    If PictureBox1.Image IsNot Nothing Then
     PictureBox1.Image.Dispose())
    End If

    Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream(bytes)
    Dim bmp = New Drawing.Bitmap(ms)
    PictureBox1.Image = bmp

    ms.Dispose()
    fps += 1
End Sub
```

The problem is it throws this error:

[image]

Saying "The parameter is invalid".

The weird part is it ONLY throws that error if

```
If PictureBox1.Image IsNot Nothing Then
 PictureBox1.BeginInvoke(Sub() PictureBox1.Image.Dispose())
End If
```

Is present, although it says "Source Not Available...." , and thus not pointing to that specific line of code, if i delete it, it works perfectly.
I also noticed, that it only throws the error if i shake the form around... changing it's location on my screen (weird ?), i can't understand why. If i leave him still, no exception is thrown... what's going on here?

Working solution: Thanks @jmcilhinney

```
 Dim newimage As Bitmap = PictureBox1.Image

    Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream(bytes)
    Dim bmp = New Drawing.Bitmap(ms)
    PictureBox1.Image = bmp

    ms.Close()
    ms.Dispose()



    If newimage IsNot Nothing Then
        newimage.Dispose()
    End If
```

Comment: You need to close your memorystream: ms.Close you are just disposing it. Best would be to wrap it in a using statement.

Comment: @Mr CoDeXeR, I agree that a Using statement should be used but that's just going to call Dispose too.  That's not an issue though, because that's all closing a MemoryStream is anyway, i.e. the current code could be improved but is not an issue as it is.

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR I thought Dispose was already calling Close for what i've read online in the past... aparently not.

Comment: Also, how can this be improved further? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the issue may be that the disposed Image is still assigned to the Image property of the PictureBox and tries to get repainted.  I would suggest assigning the Image to a local variable, setting the Image property of the PictureBox to Nothing and then disposing the Image.

Comment: What do you mean when assigning the image to a local variable? It's already created as bmp, i only need it once to be displayed on the picturebox, if i use picturebox1.image = nothing it doesn't throw any error but the problem is, it flashes blank in each frame it desplays as it is clearing it.
I want to dispose the previous image without putting the picture that is desplayed blank... this may be somekind redundant disposing should clear it, but i don't want the interface to be afected, only keeping it clean in the memory and not leaving the garbage collector more work...

Comment: I'm not talking about the new Image.  I'm talking about the existing Image, i.e. the one that you're disposing.  If you want to make absolutely sure that the PictureBox doesn't go blank in between then display the new Image before disposing the old one.

Comment: Oh, thank you, that worked (i didn't thought of that cause i never used picturebox'es in this particular case... 
Can you explain something though, when i equal the newimage to the picturebox.image, is a copy created, or the newimage removes the value from the picturebox.image?
I will change my post with the working solution.

Comment: Image is a class, i.e. a reference type, so it behaves just as all reference types do.  That means that a copy of the object is not created unless you create one.  For more information, read up on value types, reference types and the differences between them.